# R script plot with ID on xaxis and all column values on yaxis

Tags: r, ggplot2, rscript

I am new to R script and need help with plotting the data.
My data looks like this

```
  run1Seek run2Seek run3Seek
1       12       23       28
2       10       27        0
3       23       19        0
4       22       24        0
5       21       26        0
6       11       26        0
```

I need to plot the ID value on x axis and run1Seek, run2Seek, run3Seek values on y axis. Something like this in the below image:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(ggplot2)

# Random data
mat <- matrix(sample(1:100, size = 1000, replace = T), ncol = 2)
colnames(mat) <- c("Run1Seek", "Run2Seek")

# Make data frame
ds <- data.frame(ID = 1:500, mat)

# Melt to long format
ds <- reshape2::melt(ds, "ID")

# Look at data
head(ds)

# Plot
ggplot(ds, aes(x = ID, y = value, fill = variable)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```